# Alan Turing was treated with estrogen-analog, though he was gay. Shouldn't it actually increase his female-like desires?

Tags: endocrinology, homosexuality

Alan Turing was a great mathematical genius of all the time, as well was a [homosexual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexuality)-[male](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gay_males&redirect=no). However, the biography of *Alan Turing* on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) ( [Permalink](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Alan_Turing&oldid=766481425) ) tells that :

> Turing was convicted and given a choice between imprisonment and probation, which would be conditional on his agreement to undergo hormonal treatment designed to reduce [libido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libido). He accepted the option of treatment via injections of what was then called *stilboestrol* (now known as [*diethylstilbestrol*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diethylstilbestrol) or *DES*), a synthetic oestrogen; this treatment was continued for the course of one year. The treatment rendered Turing [impotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Impotence&redirect=no) and caused [gynaecomastia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gynecomastia),fulfilling in the literal sense Turing's prediction that "no doubt I shall emerge from it all a different man, but quite who I've not found out".

Though upon modern medicine, probably Turing needed no medication; but medicine (and politics) of that time; needed to prescribe some medication for Turing.

Well. But why they've chosen an Estrogen analog? Shouldn't that actually increase Turing's female-like needs and behaviors? Or maybe it indeed increased the homosexuality in Alan Turing unintentionally or intentionally?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest looking for medical logic in this sort of forced treatment, but hormonal control of behavior certainly is not as simple as "more testosterone = seeks women" and "more estrogen = seeks men." The "treatment" was given to suppress sexuality viewed as inappropriate.